# How to handle multiple bluetooth connections in python on raspberry pi?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluetooth-gatt

I have a raspberry pi 4. I am already able to communicate to one other device with the ble python backend "bleak". Here you can see come code snippets of this communication.

```
async def run(address, loop):
  async with BleakClient(address, loop=loop) as client:
    print("Connected!")
    await client.start_notify(UUID_RX, rx_data_received)
    # ENTER INPUT COMMANDS:
    got_input = input('Enter your command (q for exit!): ')
    while(got_input is not 'q'):
    ...
       await client.write_gatt_char(UUID_TX, bytearray(c[0:20]), True)
       ...

if __name__== "__main__":
  print("Connecting...")
  loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
  loop.run_until_complete(run(address, loop))
```

This works fine.
As "bleak" works with async, it is hard to extend this code for another active bluetooth connection. As you can see I need to receive data from and send data to the other ble devices.

I already searched a lot on the internet. Unfortunately, I did not found something helpful, like example code, tutorials or documentation for multiple bluetooth connections with python.

Can anyone provide some help on where to start?

Comment: The `bleak` repo has an example for two devices. https://github.com/hbldh/bleak/blob/develop/examples/two_devices.py Does this not help?

Comment: Hello ukBaz. I saw this example. For me it looks like that this example does not have two connected devices, instead this example has one device with two characteristics. Am I wrong? I do not see the device adresses (e.g.: FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF)

Comment: Ah! I see where the confusion has come from. The "address" used in that example are for the  MacOS backend. I believe if you change that to the format you require it should work. https://bleak.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/macos.html?highlight=macos#specific-features-for-the-macos-backend

Comment: Thanks for this. You were right. These adresses confused me. It looks like I simply can use my device adresses in line 38 and 39.

Comment: Unfortunately I have another problem, It says, that there is an error in line 39: "ValueError: a coroutine was expected, got <_GatheringFuture pending>"